# How can i fix the ?????? problem in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got both of mdf and ldf files from user.

He told me that it's infected. but my Symantec said it's clean.

i can attach it to SQL Server 2000. but all Thai words in all rows and tables became

"?????????????http://www.qiqigm.com/m.js"

For the "www.qiqigm.com" i can write a script to remove it

but how can i change "??????????" to the Thai language?

FYI

The collation name is THAI_CI_AS

Answer (score 2):

It seems your data has been overwritten by a [SQL injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Try casting one of the fields as `nvarchar(max)`, i.e. Unicode. If you still see question-marks then your Thai words are gone forever, and you'll need to restore a backup from before the attack date.